# rejected tcp connection does not return error

Tags: networking, tcp, go

I did some experiment on Golang net package.

When I use a client to connect a server (without close connections), I found that server had error like this:
"too many open files"
It makes sense because the file open limit set in my os.

However, I found that **client never returned errors when connecting to server**, which is weird since server had already rejected some of connection requests.

```
// Server code
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net"
)

func main() {
    listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", "localhost:7070")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    for {
        conn, err := listener.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err, conn)
            continue
        }
    }
}


// Client code
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net"
)

func main() {
    cnt := 0
    for {
        conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", "localhost:7070")
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("!", conn.RemoteAddr())
            continue
        }
        cnt++
        n, err := conn.Write([]byte("hello"))
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalln(err)
        }

        log.Println(cnt, n)

    }

}
```

Can anyone tell me what happens here?

thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TCP handshake is asynchronously performed on the server by the kernel TCP/IP stack before the server application accepts it, so even if your server code fails to accept the connection, it will be connected at the TCP level. That's why the net.Dial() succeeds.

When your server code accept of the connection fails, the TCP/IP stack will close the connection though.

net.Write() just passes data onto the local TCP/IP stack, which will asynchronously send the data. If this is done before the server code has had a chance to (fail to) accept the connection, there's no error as the tcp connection is still operational. If your client perform a 2. write, or perhaps waits a bit, net.Write() should fail too.

Comment: You're right. So, how do I ensure (or know) a message has already been sent and reached the peer server? Can I know that even if server does not response anything? Is the ACK in the TCP stack visible to users?

Comment: The TCP ACK is not visible, no. If you want to know that the remote application has received/processed the message, the remote application needs to tell you that it has done so. I.e. you need to implement your own protocol on top of TCP, and have it send some sort of "ACK" message.

Comment: Can I know that the client fails to connect to server before writing data? Is there something like connect.Ok()?

Comment: @user3619782 If the TCP connection fails to be established, net.Dial() returns an error. But as you discovered, there are many other cases, such as the one described here, that can lead to a failure too, and you cannot know many of those cases without transmitting anything to the other end.